# Set Doctype of new upload files using FTP in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using alfresco-5.2.I have enabled the FTP in alfresco,and able to upload the files successfully.but those are coming without type can anyone tell me how to set doctype and metadata for file.

Comment: Can you give us an example, as to what would doctype and metadata be? Where do you have them stored now, if anywhere?

Comment: while uploading the document i want to set doctype as "unindexed" and metadeta like page num,lifespan,expirydate etc

Comment: Can you switch to  using a more  feature-rich protocol like CMIS? Otherwise, can you make sure all files go in an "incoming" folder?

Comment: ya i can assure because the file path we are setting for a set of files @Gagravarr

Comment: Why not put a "onCreate" Rule on the incoming folder then, which sets the type and properties ?

Answer (score 1):

FTP allows you to upload the file and that's about it. Similar to copying via WebDAV or CIFS. If that is your only option you will have to follow Gagravarr's suggestion and add a folder rule to the folder that specializes the type and sets the properties as you see fit (in Share, go to the folder and click "Manage Rules").

If code is an option then you should use CMIS to upload the documents because CMIS will allow you to set the document type and set custom properties. There are CMIS clients for a number of languages including Java, Python, .NET, and others. The most widely-used client libraries can found at the [Apache Chemistry](https://chemistry.apache.org/) project.